# How can I remove all ListItems except the one having a particular value from an ItemList of a drop-down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a dropdown : myDropDown.

And I need to remove all ListItem in its item collection which does not have a value equals to '-1' ?

```
myDropDown.Items. ... // TODO: Remove all ListItems that has a value different than '-1'
```

I don't want to create a loop etc.

How can I achieve this in a most self-documenting way? I assume with a LINQ statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`, I think the good old `for` loop is the best choice here:

```
for (int i = d.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (d.Items[i].Value != "-1") d.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is the 'best?'

Comment: Assuming you are working with a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`, it's the only one that complies ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
myDropDown.Items = myDropDown.Items.Where(x => x.value != -1);
```

Comment: I think that you meant Where(x => x.value==-1).ToList();